# Why is my div within a container overlapping my footer?

Tags: css, laravel

I have what seems like a simple problem but I haven't been able to fix it.
This morning, my site started displaying an overlap of the table container into the footer.

Looking in GIT, I didn't see anything in the differentials that would have caused it from the last merge.

CSS:

```
.dashboardBackground
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ececec;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

This is the area containing the table:

```
.dashboardContent
{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0,0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
}
```

The app itself is built on the Laravel framework, so I don't think the problem is in the HTML as any pages containing tables with multiple entries, displays this problem.

I've tried using an `inline-block` property in addition to trying to fixing the footer to an absolute position at the bottom of the screen.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: bind your link correctly please

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Had to delete the image because I don't have a high enough rep; fixed now.

Comment: Please include the markup. We need to see a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

you can add

```
.dashboardContent
{
...
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

this will set your content behind the footer